# jQuery makes anchor tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change `li` tag's class on a navbar to `active` when i'm on that page.
jQuery changes `li` class to `active` but `<a>` inside it stops working. 
When I disable js file, anchor tags star to work properly. Using Django 2.0.6.

js file:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
     "use strict";

     $('ul.navbar-nav > li').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
     });
  });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

navbar:

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" id="mainNav" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
  <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">NT Photography</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">portfolio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'pictures' %}">blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">about</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();`  you are preventing the default when the li sees a click.  This will include click events that bubble up from the links inside them.

Comment: Changing the class of the `li` also seems redundant anyway if you're about to redirect away from the current page

Answer (score 0):

Remove `e.preventDefault()` to allow the event to work it's way though.

Comment: Ok, that worket. But when i redirect class `active` goes back to the first element... I'm using a base file for the navbar and extending the oher pages from it.

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault()` function in your code is preventing click event on list-items and their child elements from executing and that is why `<a>` elements inside `<li>` tags are not working. Therefore removing `e.preventDefault()` in your code will ultimately solve your problem.